# Как проверить переменную на присутствие текста?

Tags: c#

Имею:

```
string MyPerm = tip_name[32583]; // Не статичная , всегда разная
```

Бывает таким `tip_name[32583]` и таким `tip_name_2[32583]`

Если возможно, подскажите 2 варианта.

1) Как регулярным выражением убрать из строки `[23522]`

2) Как проверить переменную `MyPerm` на присутствие текста `tip_name`

Comment: Покажите код и ожидаемый результат. По тексту вопроса тяжело понять,  что и куда вы хотите записать

Comment: @PashaPash по первому вопросу разобрался и отредактировал на новый.

Comment: К сожалению, вопрос не стал понятнее. Что мешает вам просто удалить скобки в коде?

Comment: `Как проверить переменную MyPerm на присутствие текста tip_name` - [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)  - раз, [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) - два

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо большое, буду учить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, погодите, у вопрошающего не строка `"tip_name"`, а переменная.

Comment: @Arhad "Как проверить **переменную MyPerm** на присутствие **текста tip_name**" - остальное ничё не знаю....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для строки :

```
      string MyPerm = "text";
```

Проверить что строка не пустая :

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyPerm)) { }
```

Проверить что строка не null, не пустая и не состоит из одних пробелов :

```
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyPerm)) { }
```

Проверить, что строка содержит другую строку :

```
        if (MyPerm.Contains("te")) { }
```